# multithreading - Asynchronous threads in class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've got a class Foo, which have a main function and execute function. I want to start an unknown number of threads with the execute function, but when I try to compile the code I always get `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`.

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef BOT_H
#define BOT_H

#pragma once
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
class foo
{
public:
    foo(char *_server, char *_port);
    ~foo(void);
private:
    char *server;
    char *port;

    void execute(char *cmd);
    void main();
};

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <thread>
#include "bot.h"
#include "definitions.h"

using namespace std;
foo::foo(char *_server, char *_port){
        ...
}

bot::~bot(void) {
        ...
}
void bot::execute(char *command){
    ...
}
    void bot::main(){
        thread(&bot::execute, (char*)commanda.c_str()).detach();
    }
```

How should I create threads from class member functions?

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 5):

You need a `bot` object to call the member function on:

```
thread(&bot::execute, this, (char*)commanda.c_str())
                      ^^^^
```

although you really should either change the function to take either `std::string` or `const char*`. You have a minefield of undefined behaviour here, if either the function tries to modify the string, or `commanda` is destroyed while the thread is still using it.

A lambda may be more readable; and would also fix the lifetime fiasco by capturing a copy of the string:

```
thread([=]{execute((char*)commanda.c_str();})
```